# Firebase realtime database sdk not getting snapshot?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code:

```js
    database.ref('users/' + userId + '/data/').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            dailySteps = snapshot.val();
        }
        else {
            console.warn("No prior user data availible.");
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

And the following database structure:
[image: Firebase Realtime Database node layout]

Daily step is a list with 31 elements. When I try the following

```js
 database.ref('users/' + userId).once('value').then(function (snapshot) { etc...
```

I get the userdata perfectly fine, so I know a few things:
A. Authentication is fine, this is not a problem with database rules
B. UserID is fine so this is not a problem with that
C. Firebase JS SDK is fine so this is not a problem with that
But when I try the code you saw at the top with the data path added on which does exist, I get a null snapshot! I've tried everything, using database.child instead of ref, using .once, using .get, and nothing will work! What is going on and why can't I fetch this data? I'm running this on the firebase hosting emulator out of the command line at localhost in case it's important.

If people still want to know these are my database rules:
[image: Firebase Realtime Database rules.]

Comment: How is `userId` initialized?

Comment: I'm using firebase authentication so it's just using the userid from that, what are you thinking? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I'm thinking that we need to see how `userId` is initialized as it's the most likely cause of being unable to read data.

Comment: Alright I'll update the post next time I'm at my computer. I'm able to read user data like email and name and profile picture fine though. User id is access through firebase.auth.currentuser().uid btw

Comment: How do you know the snapshot is null? Are you getting an error and/or something printed to console?

Comment: @Jay Snapshot.exists is returning false and when I try to access snapshot.val it gives null

Comment: Just for clarity - if the snapshot doesn't exist, this code `console.log(snapshot.val());` should not run. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: No, I'm getting console.warn message I wrote, I had thrown an extra console.log(snapshot.val()); into the failure state before which is how I determined that. @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, turns out all along I was being the big dumb dumb and this wasn't something you guys could have seen since I didn't post all my code,
TLDR: I was deleting and replacing the data on page load at the same time I tried to read it, forgot doing a .set on a dir replaces everything including children.